# Разделение таблицы odt

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, libre-office

Работаю с odt документом через xml, по причине безопасной безопасности на работе. Нужно создавать отчёты в которых могут быть таблицы, которые больше одной страницы и заезжают на следующие.

Возможно ли как-то понять, как будет расположен элемент (не обязательно таблица), чтобы Разбить на два или сделать перенос на новую страницу.

xml создаю через python храня элементы изначально в объектах, а потом при вызове метода save записываю в заготовленные шаблон.

Comment: Создайте минимальный пример из случайных данных, который бы воспроизводил вашу проблему, тогда вероятность того что вам помогут резко подскочет.

Comment: вообще-то вам, конечно, надо бы для начала определиться: то ли вам требуется «разделение таблицы odt» (как написано в заголовке вопроса), то ли вам надо «понять, как будет расположен элемент» (как написано в тексте вопроса). чтобы изменить вопрос, нажмите [edit].